# Magento 2 how to get session value in custom form

Tags: magento2

Magento 2 how to get session value in the custom form that is customer name and order id in custom form.[image]

[image]

Comment: If customer have multiple orders then which order id you need to show?

Comment: As my custom form redirect from My Dashboard

Comment: I think you are not getting my point? One customer might have multiple orders, then which order id you want to show in the form?

Comment: I can set to dropdown  Sukumar Gorai

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try below code to get customer name, email and contact number.

```
    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $customerSession = $objectManager->get('Magento\Customer\Model\Session');
    $customer = $objectManager->get('Magento\Customer\Model\Customer')->load($customerSession->getId());
    $cust_name =  '';
    $cust_email ='';
    $cust_telephone ='';
    if($customerSession->isLoggedIn()) {
        $cust_name =  $customerSession->getCustomer()->getName();
        $cust_email = $customerSession->getCustomer()->getEmail();

        if(!empty($customer->getPrimaryBillingAddress())){
            $cust_telephone = $customer->getPrimaryBillingAddress()->getTelephone();
        }
    }
```

However, its not good practice to use $objectManager directly in template file. It would be great if you can add this code to your custom block and call from there.

Can you provide more details about order id. Generally order id could be get at order success page only.

Comment: Thanks for comment Himmat Paliwal i need to display name and order id  in a custom form after login

Comment: Okay, there would be multiple orders for a customer, do you need specific order id of that customer? You can get other details using above code (Manage in your custom block to follow best practice).

Comment: Thanks for comment Himmat Paliwal I am not getting any value in the custom form and in other pages I am getting, issues is I don't include a session in the custom module, how can I include the session in my module

Comment: You don't need to include session separately, Magento itself creates all the required sessions at particular events/actions.

Comment: I am not getting value in my module..

Comment: Have you logged in to any customer account?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86703/discussion-between-trilok-kumar-and-himmat-paliwal).

Comment: @HimmatPaliwal, Please add the full path where the code and file need to be created. Then this answer will be used to beginers also